# Multi Language in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make my app in two language.I have tried lots of localization code but it doesn't work. please help me i am not using storyboard . i have more than 15 xib files.

when i have made in single language i take a constant file and describes  all label and button text.
but after some time i have two make app in two language .In my app  i have option to select language by user.
my infoPlist.strings code given below

```
    for turkish lang
         "TT_TEXT" = "merhaba";
     for English lang
        "TT_TEXT" = "hello";
```

and at calling point i write

```
        [self setTitleOnNavBar:NSLocalizedString(@"TT_TEXT", nil)];
```

it treats TT_TEXT as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code -

```
NSString *bundle_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings"inDirectory:nil forLocalization:@"en"];
NSBundle *localized_bundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:[bundle_path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
NSString *str = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"TT_TEXT",nil,localized_bundle, nil);
[self setTitleOnNavBar:str];
```

write your language country code in place of `@"en"` and use it.

Comment: First you have to creat Localizable.strings(English) and Localizable.strings(Turkish) files in your project after that you can use them with above code. for Turkish localization code you have to use @"tr" in place of @"en".

Comment: i have already creted both file  and write the code in that file     for turkish lang
         "TT_TEXT" = "merhaba";
     for English lang
        "TT_TEXT" = "hello";
can u tell me how to switch between these two language . i have given user to select language in app

Comment: When user select English language you have to use @"en" and when user select Turkish language you have to use @"tr". you have to write it in user language selection action. then you can switch between these two language. if any more query you can chat me here is my mail id - 4santosh.sharma@gmail.com